# AngularJS adding authorization to routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth, angular-ui-router

How can I add authorization to AngularJS and ui.router?
I'm using the modulg ng-oauth https://github.com/andreareginato/oauth-ng

Can I use the following examples from the page http://andreareginato.github.io/oauth-ng/?

```
$scope.$on('oauth:login', function(event, token) {
  console.log('Authorized third party app with token', token.access_token);
});

$scope.$on('oauth:logout', function(event) {
  console.log('The user has signed out');
});

$scope.$on('oauth:loggedOut', function(event) {
  console.log('The user is not signed in');
});

$scope.$on('oauth:denied', function(event) {
  console.log('The user did not authorize the third party app');
});

$scope.$on('oauth:expired', function(event) {
  console.log('The access token is expired. Please refresh.');
});

$scope.$on('oauth:profile', function(profile) {
  console.log('User profile data retrieved: ', profile);
});
```

Thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 0):

You could create some constant roles like this:

```
.constant('USER_ROLES', {
    ALL: '*', //@unused
    ADMIN: 'ROLE_ADMIN';
    USER: 'ROLE_USER',
    ANONYMOUS: 'ROLE_ANONYMOUS' 
})
```

Add this custom data/constants to your states:

```
$stateProvider.state('myapp.admin', {
    url: '/admin',
    .....
    data : {
        authorizedRoles : [USER_ROLES.ADMIN] //Thes
    }
}
```

So when you authenticate and retrieve these roles from your database you can store this in your user object and session so you can eventually verify this when a route changes...

In your auth service (apart from logging in, logging out etc...) you add the following methods.

```
isAuthenticated: function () {
    return session.hasSession();
},

isAuthorized: function (authorizedRoles) {
    if (!angular.isArray(authorizedRoles)) {
        authorizedRoles = [authorizedRoles];
    }

    var roles = session.roles();

    var roleIncluded = roles.some(function (role) {
        return (authorizedRoles.indexOf(role) != -1);
    });

    return (session.hasSession() && roleIncluded);
},
```

So when you change the route in the applications `.run` block validation occurs and prevention is possible.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
    if (authService.isAuthenticated()) {
        if (next.data.authorizedRoles === null) {
            handle();
        }
        if (!authService.isAuthorized(next.data.authorizedRoles)) {
            handle();
        }
    } else {
        handle();
    }
}
```

Ofcourse this is just an example and bear in mind there are other solutions.