# Making AngularJS ui-router / app wait for $http data to prevent FOUC

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following question... or situation. I have states defined in my AngularJS app, like so...

```
$stateProvider
            .state('myApp', {
                abstract: true,
                template: '<ui-view/>'
            })
            .state('myApp.stateOne', {
                url: 'state1',
                templateUrl: '/an/views/state-1.html',
                controller: 'StateOneCtrl'
            })
            .state('myApp.stateTwo', {
                url: 'state2',
                templateUrl: '/an/views/state-2.html'
                controller: 'StateTwoCtrl'
            })
            .state('myApp.stateThree', {
                url: 'state3',
                templateUrl: '/an/views/state-3.html'
                controller: 'StateThreeCtrl'
            })
```

There are more states and I have changed the naming for this example, but suppose I need to check if the user is allowed to see / load `'mayApp.stateThree'`. I can determine this by asking the backend. I have a service (in this example called `IsAllowedService`) to deal with this requests / provide the access and normally I would write the logic to do the check in the `.run()` block in my app.js file for example:

```
.run(['IsAllowedService', '$state', function (IsAllowedService, $state) {

        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState) {

            // check if we are going to sfm.addContacts and if we are allowed to...
            if (toState.name === 'myApp.stateThree') {
                IsAllowedService.checkIfIsAllowed().then(function (resp) {
                    if(resp.allowed === false) {
                        $state.go('myApp.stateOne');
                    }
                });
            }

        });

}]);
```

This works well but doesn't wait until we get the result from the service so 'mayApp.stateThree' is loaded then we a redirected if necessary. So we get a quick flash of the page before we are redirected. I could put the same code into the `'StateThreeCtrl'` but I still get the flash / FOUC. Would it be possible to resolve this when defining the states, I know this won't work but something like this...

```
.state('myApp.stateThree', {
    url: '/an/state3',
    templateUrl: '/an/views/state-3.html'
    controller: 'StateThreeCtrl',
    resolve: {
        isAllowed : function () {
        IsAllowedService.checkIfIsAllowed().then(function (resp) {
            return resp;
            })
        }
    }
```

I realise that I wouldn't be able to inject the service (or even the `$http` service) but is it possible for me to somehow pause the loading of the view / controller of '`mayApp.stateThree`' until I get the result from `IsAllowedService.checkIfIsAllowed()`. Any advice on how to structure my app / code would be appreciated. I have used ng-cloak in my HTML view but this did nothing!

Comment: These are predefined user roles or some criteria gathered during runtime?

Comment: The outcome of checkIfIsAllowed() is predefined.

Comment: You *should* use `resolve`, and you can inject services - not sure why you say that you can't - `resolve: { isAllowed: function(IsAllowedSvc){ return IsAllowedSvc.check()... } }`

Comment: The resolve should work but it is not a great solution. Imagine you're working with RequireJS, or similar, to work modular and load pages when they are required. This would imply you have to load a page and then verify on that page whether you can see it or not. It can and _should_ be restricted much _earlier_.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you're doing it almost right in the application's run block. Except you are not preventing anything. You can achieve that by adding:

```
  event.preventDefault(); //Prevent from going to the page
```

Furthermore, you can add custom data to your $states , which will allow you to verify those conditions with your criteria. e.g.:

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
  controller: 'HomeController as home',   
  url: '/home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  data: { roles: [ROLES.ANONYMOUS] }}); //This can be any condition 
$stateProvider.state('user', {
  controller: 'UserController as user', 
  url: '/user',
  templateUrl: 'user.html', 
  data: { roles: [ROLES.ADMIN, ROLES.USER] }});
```

You can retrieve this custom data in the **$stateChangeStart** event:

```
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
    if (!yourService.isAuthorized(next.data.roles)) { 
      event.preventDefault(); //Prevent from going to the page -> no flickering
      $state.go('403'); //Or whatever is desired.
    } 
  });
```

You see the flickering because you're using a **Promise** and the first page only gets redirected when the promise is furfilled. You can stop the flickering  by preventing the default action, authorize and continue your flow as you desire when the promise resolves.

```
       if (toState.name === 'myApp.stateThree') {
            event.preventDefault(); //preventing the request.
            IsAllowedService.checkIfIsAllowed().then(function (resp) {
                if(resp.allowed === false) {
                    $state.go('myApp.stateOne');
                } else { //he actually is allowed to go to state three.
                   $state.go('myApp.stateThree');
                } 
            }, function() { //in case the server has no answer
              $state.go('myApp.stateOne'); //you probably want to prevent it too
        } );
```

In my opinion, if these conditions do not change during runtime, i.e. user role based, you can retrieve them upon user verification so you don't need a promise to begin with. Hope this helps.

I made a similar post [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31020556/angularjs-adding-authorization-to-routes/31024112#31024112) and added a `working` [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6slTHbRK7LtuhdKlmPUH?p=info).

Comment: Hi, if you look at the examples I gave the second code example is the .run() block

Comment: I'll update it soon, sorry I went over it too quickly.

Comment: Actually there is no need to resolve this in your view. When you declare a state you can add custom data to it. So when you login or get the predefined conditions for views from your server: i.e. when your applications boots (or on login) you verify those conditions with the page. Based on that you prevent the page from being loaded. Here is a very small [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/6slTHbRK7LtuhdKlmPUH?p=preview).

Comment: Sorry it took a while but I needed some sleep. =P