# Check login in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

HTML Code:-

```
 <html>
    <head>
            <style>
            .splash {
                    display: none;
            }

            [ng-cloak].splash {
                    display: block !important;
            }

            .splash {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    height:100%;
                    width:100%;    
                    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
                    opacity: 0.6;
                    background: #000;
            }

            .splash h2 {
                    text-align: center;
                    font-size: 4em;
                    color:white;                   
            }
            </style>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div class="splash" ng-cloak="">
                    <h2>Loading</h2>
            </div> 
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>


                <form action=welcome.html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="validateCtrl"
                    name="myForm" ng-cloak="" novalidate >

                    <p>Username:<br>
                    <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" required>
                        <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
                            <span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
                        </span>
                        </p>

                        <p>Email:<br>
                        <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required>
                            <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
                                <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
                                <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">Invalid email address.</span>
                            </span>
                            </p>

                            <p>
                            <input type="submit" 
                                ng-disabled="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid ||  
                                myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
                                </p>

                </form>


            <script>
                var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
                app.controller('validateCtrl', function($scope) {
                               $scope.user = 'John Doe';
                               $scope.email = 'john.doe@gmail.com';
                               });

                    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

                    setTimeout(function() {
                            body.setAttribute('ng-app', 'myApp');
                            angular.bootstrap(body, ['ng', 'myApp']);
                    }, 2000);
            </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have done up to this.Now I want to check whether the user has login or not. If user has not logged in he/she must not be allowed to reach the index.html file. User should be redirected to main page. Can any one help me to solve this problem using angularJS.

Comment: Use ngRoute. Before loading to you the view of the requested url, it can check for some value to be resolved. Thus, you can create a deferred object (ie, var def = $q.defer()), and after checking login, you can resolve or reject (eg, def.resolve()). ngRoute, depending on this, you show the page or not. And if it is rejected, you can return to login page. If you could read until here and want more, I would also explain that how.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a http://plnkr.co/edit/iv7jkFI8KclxFSRAtko9?p=preview for your case. I used `validateUser` function which runs on Login button click and validates the input against the model value.

```
$scope.validateUser = function() {
    if (_correctData.user == $scope.user && _correctData.email == $scope.email) {
      console.log('Correct login');
      $scope.wrongCredentials = false;
      document.location = 'index.html';
    } else {
      console.log('wrongCredentials');
      $scope.wrongCredentials = true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply. But my problem was that i want to restrict user from assesing the welcome.html from browser without going from login page. can you please help me with that.

Comment: I need to check the angularjs route to check the route of the user. Can anybody provide me some demose

Answer (score 0):

The question you're asking is, the way I understand it,  a combination of smaller problems you need to tackle. It appears that you are in need of multiple states (views) that represent the different visual parts of your application, an authentication service that verifies user credentials with a back-end server and restricts access when the visitor is not authorized/authenticated and lastly a service that will handle communication between the server and application.

AngularJS already provides this functionality in the [ng-route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) module but there is a more extensive alternative called [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

As mentioned above, a service that logs a user in and out, checks for authentication and authorization is needed. In case you don't know how to begin , [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) might be a good place to start.

As you don't want to store credentials in your AngularJS application , you'll need a service that is able to handle the requests and responses between your application and your server. This service could also be used for different resources, fetching data etc..

I have created a small `demo` a while back , which you can find on this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6slTHbRK7LtuhdKlmPUH?p=info). This demo is a role based application with anonymous, users and admin roles (without the communication between the server/application). A more detailed explanation on how this demo is build can be found in a previous post I made on SO, which you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31020556/angularjs-adding-authorization-to-routes/31024112#31024112).